# I want to have a global struct with array but I don't know how I should do this

Tags: c

I need a global struct with array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define MAX_STR_LEN 80
struct students
{
    char firstname[MAX_STR_LEN];
    char lastname[MAX_STR_LEN];
    char id[11];
    float average;
};
int students_count;
struct students *students = calloc(students_count, sizeof *students);
int main() {
    puts("How many students do you have ? ");
    scanf("%d", &students_count);
    return 0;
}
```

And I don't know whats the meaning of this error.

> Initializer element is not a compile-time constant

The reason that I want to do this is giving some options to user on the students list for example adding or removing student... so I should have global struct to define the functions that I need.

Comment: I bet a line number is also given, so please refer to the line involved. The function call to `calloc` is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have executable statements such as function calls outside of a function.  You need to set the value of `students` inside of the `main` function, and then only after setting the value of `students_count`.

```
int students_count;
struct students *students;

int main() {
    puts("How many students do you have ? ");
    scanf("%d", &students_count);
    students = calloc(students_count, sizeof *students);
    return 0;
}
```